# Can I use the answer "It better." in this example?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, spoken-english

Can I use the answer "It better." in this example?

> 'I'm sure your dedication to the job will pay off soon,' said John.

> 'It better,' replied his friend.

Is this dialogue correct?

I'm not sure where I found this (It better), but I guess it means something like, "It (my dedication) better pay off soon otherwise I'm gonna be in trouble". Or "It must pay off soon, after all I've been through".

Am I right?

Comment: A slightly less colloquial version would be "It had better [pay off soon]". with the sense "I hope it does, as I really need it to." It's 'correct' in that it is a realistic representation of very informal speech.

Comment: You might actually *hear* imperative forms like ***You better do what I say***, but it wouldn't usually be a good idea to *write* it like that (as @KateBunting points out, it should be ***You HAD better do it***). Even if you're writing "casual" reported speech in a narrative context, you wouldn't normally want to explicitly reflect the fact that your (fictitious) speaker would be likely to omit that word. You'll just confuse your (real-world) reader for no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this dialog is correct, and so is your interpretation. It reads smoothly to a native English speaker. "It had better" is more formal, but doesn't fit as well here.

Comment: I'd welcome a comment explaining the downvote(s).

Comment: Downvoters tend to prefer anonymity. But I don't think it's deserved either, even if your answer is rather brief, and the dialogue is possible rather than correct; so I've upvoted it. A more substantial answer would stand you in better stead.